# Would the hydrogen-bonded polymer hexaamminecobalt(III) hexakis(trifluoromethyl)cobaltate(III) be soluble in water?

Tags: polymers, hydrogen-bond

It is clear that both the hexaamminecobalt(III) ion and the hexakis(trifluoromethyl)cobaltate(III) ion are both low spin (the former is already low spin, and the trifluoromethyl ligand is clearly softer than the ammine ligand) and therefore valence isoelectronic to each other, since the Jahn-Teller effect cannot occur. Since their topological connectivities are the same, they must both be of the "same shape" and therefore be able to form hydrogen bonded networks using the ammine protons and trifluoromethyl fluorides.

**Question**: Would the solvation properties (dipole moments, hydrogen bonding abilities, and the like) of water sufficient to solubilize the hydrogen-bonded polymer $\ce{[Co(NH3)6][Co(CF3)6]}$? I'm asking this, since the very reason that "$\ce{HF}$ is a weak acid in dilute aqueous solution" is that the $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{F-}$ hydrogen bond is too strong for the $\ce{H3O^+}$ to dissociate and "display its acidity".

Comment: Do we know that the proposed salt exists?

Comment: The cation already exists. As for the anion, hydrofluorination of the known cobalticyanide anion should do the trick.

Comment: Ammonium and hydroxide ions exist, but except perhaps under extreme high-pressure conditions like the interior of Neptune there is no ammonium hydroxide. I ask about the salt as a whole, not its parts.

Comment: Check their shapes. They perfectly fit in a halite structure supported by H-F hydrogen bonds.